# Adding TextView in LinearLayout like chips same as Gmail address suggestion

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been creating `Chips` like Gmail and most of the social android application for address.

#### Que

*I've been appending values in `LinearLayout` is working fine as long as it less than device width. As soon as it's length more than device width it gets jumble up.*

*How can a preserve same behaviour in every enviornment?*

*Expected Behaviour :*

[image: Expected Behaviour]

*What i got*

[image] [image]

Code Snippet:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chipsBoxLayout" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
<!--Layout to add Chips like Gmail application-->
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1);
params.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);

Iterator<Contact> iterContacts = contacts.iterator();
while(iterContacts.hasNext()) 
{   
  Contact contact = iterContacts.next();
  TextView t = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
  t.setLayoutParams(params);
  t.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
  t.setText(contact.getContactName());
  t.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  t.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
  chipsBoxLayout.addView(t);
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) and [this](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per Rethinavel Pillai ,

[FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout) works as expected in adding views which i will accomodate by itself if it's added inside `FlowLayout`.

Code Snippet:

```
<com.FlowLayout
            android:id="@+id/chips_box_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="start"
             >
</com.FlowLayout>
```

---

```
FlowLayout chipsBoxLayout;
chipsBoxLayout = (FlowLayout)findViewById(R.id.chips_box_layout);


FlowLayout.LayoutParams params = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

Iterator<Contact> iterContacts = contacts.iterator();
while(iterContacts.hasNext()) 
{   
  Contact contact = iterContacts.next();
  TextView t = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
  t.setLayoutParams(params);
  t.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
  t.setText(contact.getContactName());
  t.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  t.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
  chipsBoxLayout.addView(t);
}
```

[image]

Comment: This layout doesn't work well in scrollview/recycler view. The elements added are not displayed. https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout works better in such scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You use LinearLayout, but google don't use it. Linear layout will not break lines and will output everything to one line.
Chips in gmail works inside ordinary textView. It uses spannable string to output images instead of text, or background color, or smth else.
Look here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/ex/chips/RecipientEditTextView.java#RecipientEditTextView
There is code how it works.

Comment: Thanks! It's way to go! But i need simple solution than that.

Comment: ok, read this article:
http://www.kpbird.com/2013/02/android-chips-edittext-token-edittext.html. There are a lot of code, but there you can understand how to implement this in your case

Comment: @VikalpPatel If it's solved your problem, don't remember to mark this ansver as solution =)

Answer (score 2):

FlowLayout will work, find the URL given below,

https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

@Rethinavel Pillai is right

Answer (score 1):

There are `Chips` implemented as a **Material design component**:

[image]

Definition:
[material.io/design/components/chips.html#input-chips](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#input-chips)

Android lib:
[material.io/develop/android/components/chip](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is you using

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

how about you use weight sum instead...?

Answer (score -3):

Try That:
use weight property:
I have use that in my app and that work fine, its a very useful also you and save the time.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lLListImages"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
         android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
         android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I agree with `WeightSum` as long as it's embedded in xml. I'm trying to add tags in that `LinearLayout` which is unknown to me also as its been fetched from internet.

Comment: that is not the reason of down the vote, that is my own work not copy from internet ok

Comment: It's wrong answer. Linear layout will not break line and will not to draw child on multiple lines.

Comment: @EngrWaseemArain number of text not fixed that's why some one down vote ur answer bcz its totally waste of time.

Comment: Why undo downvotes? Your solution is wrong. It doesn't help to solve a problem. You suggest to use linearlayout, but linearlayout has another behavior. You don't help and ask to waste time for your "solution".