# Design dynamic UI like in given Image

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I want to create UI like shown in picture. TextView with close button should be added dynamically. Total view width is fixed. Added view(TextView + close button) should adjust it self according to parent width.
How could it be possible. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216718/adding-textview-in-linearlayout-like-chips-same-as-gmail-address-suggestion/23216852#23216852

Comment: @Demand Thnks for quick response. I l check it and let you know.

Comment: @Demand Hi, Post your comment as answer.I will vote it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at my answer here [Adding TextView in LinearLayout like chips same as Gmail address suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216718/adding-textview-in-linearlayout-like-chips-same-as-gmail-address-suggestion/23216852#23216852)
It solve your problem based on TextView and SpannableString, like it work in Gmail and Google Hangouts.