# android : how to create GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a requirement to create a gridview like as below:

[image]

First I thought of a way, to go with StaggeredGridLayoutManager but that too has static span. If I pass span of two just columns will be created, even if space is available to another item.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: This will help you.. https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips other link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216718/adding-textview-in-linearlayout-like-chips-same-as-gmail-address-suggestion

Comment: Thanks.. Seems `FlowLayout` is what I want..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This flow layout might help you.

[FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)

Answer (score 3):

Check below links, it might help you.

1. Use multiple autocompleted textview :Bubble-Text-Library(you can change view from xml file also) [Link](https://github.com/AmaldevTA/Android-Chip-Bubble-Text-Library)
2. android-chips(suggested by @ Suhas Bachewar)  [Link](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips)
3. chipview(multi custom color) [Link](https://github.com/Plumillon/ChipView)

and many more are there

Comment: Thanks for providing me options to my requirement. Voted for useful