# Create dynamic textview like this in example

Tags: android, layout

I need to dynamically create a layout like this. Textview can be dynamic.

[image: How do I create layout like in hyperlink]

I don't have enough reputation so unable to post image here. Sorry about that.

How am I supposed to go forward as layout manager will only go in one direction either horizontal or vertical.

Please provide some example. If question is duplicate please provide link to original question.

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I created a linear layout and kept on adding textview but its not working as expected.

Comment: I don't understand why negative marks on question. If something wrong then preach, why just down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Amir for your hint "Chips" it helped me to google in this direction and I found a similar question on stackoverflow. link to this is [Adding TextView in LinearLayout like chips same as Gmail address suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216718/adding-textview-in-linearlayout-like-chips-same-as-gmail-address-suggestion)

Please close this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

They are Chips. You can use these libraries

https://github.com/DoodleScheduling/android-material-chips

https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips

https://github.com/eyeem/chips-android

Comment: Thanks. I will try your solution. If it works for me. I will mark it as answer.