# How to display all the elements of ArrayList as Chips in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-chips

I have an `ArrayList<String>` like this `[Angularjs, JavaScript, Css]`

In my Adapter where I get the `ArrayList` of tags from another Intent. I tried to display all the elements of the `ArrayList` as **Chips** with the below approach, but I get only the last element of the ArrayList. I only see *one* Chip with the last element of the ArrayList.

```
for (String tag: card.getTags()) {
  Log.d(TAG, "tag - " + tag);
  holder.tags.setText(tag);
}
```

Could anyone please guide, how do I change my code to display all the elements of the ArrayList as `Chips`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about [Chips](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/).

Add a `ChipGroup` in xml layout where you want to show your chips

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
 android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 app:chipSpacingVertical="2dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now you can use this method to add your ArrayList as `Chip` in `ChipGroup` :

```
private void addChip(String pItem, ChipGroup pChipGroup) {
    Chip lChip = new Chip(this);
    lChip.setText(pItem);
    lChip.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_text));
    lChip.setChipBackgroundColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.chip_bg));

    pChipGroup.addView(lChip, pChipGroup.getChildCount() - 1);
  }
```

Comment: Excellent, that was it! It worked. I just did `holder.chipgroup.add(chip)`

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you're replacing `tags` in your `forEach` Loop of the holder. You have only one holder and keep updating that till loop ends; that's the reason you have last `chip/tag`

If you are referring to [ChipGroup](https://material.io/components/chips/) of MaterialComponents.

```
ChipGroup chipGroup = new ChipGroup(parentView.getContext());

String[] genres = {"Thriller", "Comedy", "Adventure"};
for(String genre : genres) {
   Chip chip = new Chip(parentView.getContext());
   chip.setText(genre);
   chipGroup.addView(chip);
}
```

---

I assume you must be using `RecyclerView` as I see the holder in your snippet.

Following is the view hierarchy; I am assuming you are trying to achieve; if not then you can use the same line of logic to move around those pieces

- RecyclerView

  - Each Item/View

    - Tags - Multiple Tag using `FlowLayout` - Adding multiple tags in view

You need to `bind` each item in your RecyclerView.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final YourViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ...
    // assuming you have FlowLayout in recyclerview view item
    // do add holder pattern to flowlayout as well
    fillAutoSpacingLayout(card.getTags(), holder.flowLayout);
}
```

Here I'm using [FlowLayout](https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout) to add chips or tags inside each view of RecyclerView.

Binding each item/View inside onBindViewHolder:

```
private void fillAutoSpacingLayout(ArrayList<String> tags, FlowLayout flowLayout) {

    for (String tag : tags) {
        TextView textView = buildLabel(tag);
        flowLayout.addView(textView);
    }
}

private TextView buildLabel(String text) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
    textView.setPadding((int)dpToPx(16), (int)dpToPx(8), (int)dpToPx(16), (int)dpToPx(8));
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.label_bg);

    return textView;
}

private float dpToPx(float dp){
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Moreover, you can refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216718/adding-textview-in-linearlayout-like-chips-same-as-gmail-address-suggestion/23217727#23217727) as it's on the same lines.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer but I'm using a `ChipGroup` and inside it I want to set the Chips which come from ArrayList. I should have mentioned that in my question itself. Could you please guide how to achieve this ?

Comment: @Pavan Ahh! If I could have sense you're referring to `ChipGroup` of MaterialComponent; I could have posted an answer within a couple of minutes.